# How to use ACL of Tizen

Tags: android, compatibility, porting, tizen

I'm new to Tizen.

Searching ahead to have Android apps developed already to work on Tizen, I found Tizen can run Android/Bada apps using Application Compatibility Layer (ACL)

Could someone please throw some light on how do I use this to run my Android apps on Tizen ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to submit your apps to Nexva, wich is an AppMall content partner. Any Tizen device with ACL (=Dalvik clone) is the same as an Android device. Infraware's Polaris App Generator (PAG) is almost the same concept btw